# What is the best way to add data to a list in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using firebase realtime db, and I'm storing a list of string in a particular storage reference. Currently, to add something to the list

I'm doing the following steps.

1. Read the database childreference
2. get the datasnapshot and check if it is null (which means first
   time)
3. if it is null, directly set your local list
4. if `dataSnapshot.getValue();` not null then (already data present in
   the db, so need to append the new data to th e end of it.)
           save the remote list from  `dataSnapshot.getValue();` to a local variable.

   then add the new data to the end of it
5. now the local list contains all the items in remote as well as new
   items. save this to the child reference

Below is the code I have written for that

```
DatabaseReference reference = root()
        .child(userId)
        .child(list_id);
reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        reference.removeEventListener(this);
        List<String> value = new ArrayList<>();
        if (dataSnapshot.getValue() == null) {
            value.add(message);
        } else {
            if (dataSnapshot.getValue() instanceof List && ((List) dataSnapshot.getValue()).size() > 0 && ((List) dataSnapshot.getValue()).get(0) instanceof String) {
                value = (List<String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                value.add(message);
            }
        }
        reference.setValue(value, (databaseError, databaseReference) -> {
            finish();
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        finish();
    }

     private void finish() {
        Log.e(TAG,"save finished");
    }
});
```

Thats a lot of steps to do a simple operation. Also , all the time I'm pulling the whole data from remote and appending the new data to it.

is there any easy way to do this?  I tried with the 'push()' method as follows

```
DatabaseReference reference = root()
    .child(userId)
    .child(list_id).push();
```

But it adds a new key always to the value I add. Can anyone explain what is the proper way to do it with less code?

**UPDATE:**
My db structure is as shown below

[image]

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: Its a simple hierarchy of a list of String as you can see in the code `root()
        .child("list")
        .child(list_id);`
`root()` will return the reference for the root node of a user, which contains a key called `list` which is holding a key value pair with key String and value `List<String>`

Comment: Basically `root()` will return the users root referee .
It wil have users comments on each date, where dateString is the key for each list. Hope u understood the structure

Comment: Rather than explaining how your database looks like, add its structure in JSON format or at least a screenshot.

Comment: @AlexMamo db structure image added

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution you gave it's very good but why to remove the listener inside the callback?
I'll write you the code to be more simpler. Please see it below:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference listIdRef = rootRef.child("list").child(list_id);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String comment = ds.getValue(String.class);
            list.add(comment);
        }
        //Do what you need to do with your list
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
    }
};
listIdRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Don't ignore errors.

The simplest way in which you can add a new child in your `08-10-18` node, without the need to get the enitire list, would be using only the following lines of code:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("5", "comment55");
rootRef.child("list").child(list_id).updateChildren(map);
```

But even a better solution would be to use instead of lists, maps and the children should be added using the `push()` method. So your database structure should look like this:

```
Fireabase-root
    |
    --- usr100
          |
          --- 08-10-18
                |
                --- randomId: "comment1"
                |
                --- randomId: "comment2"
                |
                --- randomId: "comment3"
                |
                --- randomId: "comment4"
```

And the code should look like this:

```
String key = rootRef.child("list").child(list_id).push().getKey();
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(key, "comment5");
rootRef.child("list").child(list_id).updateChildren(map);
```

In this case you don't have to worry about the key, which is not a number anymore. Without the help of the `push()` method, you need to get the entire list, as explained in the first part of my answer, add the new element and the update the list in the database.

Comment: Removed the listener because it will end up in a recursive `onDataChange` event trigger since the `setValue` will again cause to trigger the `ValueEventListener` in the `listIdRef` and it will go  infinitely since you are not removing listener

Comment: @doe There is no need for that. Have you tried my solution above?

Comment: Your solution is the same right? No need to call `reference.setValue` after modifying data?

Comment: This solution is only getting the data, not writing it to the database. Isn't this what you want?

Comment: Your solution is almost same as what I have already done. Also as you said, If I did not remove the listener , I'm getting recursive `onDataChange`. In your solution also, we need to copy the entire remote db values to local, then upload the new list. I was searching for a solution where firebase will always append  data to a child, so that we always send our newly creates list only without bothering about all those pulling and append logic

Comment: You'll never get a recursive `onDataChange` even if you are not removing the listener in the callback. So you say yowant to add for example, another child under `08-10-18` that looks like this: `5: ""comment5` , right?

Comment: Oh, I understand. I'll edit my answer in short time.

Comment: As you have mentioned in the updated answer, the `push()` also I tried which is given in my question. But it adds a random key to all my values, which I don't want.

Comment: Just finished to update my answer. Please see the entire update. Ony the use of `push()` method can help you achieve what you, otherwise you'll need to get the entire list, add new element, update it in the database. With those pushed keys you only need to use a few lines of code without getting anything from the database. Which also means **less read operations**, which is very important.

Comment: Using those pushed keys, is a  quite common practice when it comes to Firebase. There is nothing to worry about. Are very helpful.

Comment: Hmm..Understood. So, I think  firebase should provide some handy API to make this kind of operations easy. This push stuff making my db ugly by adding those random keys

Comment: Ja, that's the way it is. The same thing it is also happening in Cloud Firestore, the new database from Google. Might be ugly but will solve your problem for sure and will also help you write less code.

Comment: I found a simpler version of the same process, with less lines of codes and I have added it as a new answer. Though, it uses `Tasks.await` which will block the current thread and handles the callback internally.  But we can achieve the same  in less lines of code. Please have a look into my answer

Comment: True, but in my case, I do all these operations inside an RxJava Observable chain , which is executing in an `io` thread. So, my these tasks will  always be executed in a background thread. Will that make any issue?

Comment: Without seeing your code I cannot be much of a help. So please post another question with the necessary details, so me and other users can help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an update to the existing accepted answer, which I tried and working. This is the same process with less lines of code, without using the `ValueEventListener` and making use of the `updateChildren` method as mentioned in the accepted answer.

```
     DatabaseReference reference = deviceRootReference().child(userId).child(list_id).push();
     Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
     map.put(reference.getKey(), comment);
     Tasks.await(reference.updateChildren(map));
```

**NOTE**: This code performs the db write synchronously (Tasks.await blocks the thread), so the above piece of code should run in a background thread only